# java.util.NoSuchElementException: Could not create a validated object, cause: ValidateObject failed

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling

I wonder what the following exception means. I get this when I set testOnBorrow=ture. If I set testOnBorrow=false, I won't get this.

I'm using MySQL 5.1.66 and commons-pool-1.5.5.jar

`Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Could not create a validated object, cause: ValidateObject failed
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1203)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver.connect(PoolingDriver.java:180)
        ... 7 more`

Answer (score 1):

I think you mistyped `true`.

Your code:

```
testOnBorrow=ture
```

should be:

```
testOnBorrow=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Tomcat documentation says about testOnBorrow...

testOnBorrow:

```
(boolean) The indication of whether objects will be validated before being borrowed from the pool. 
If the object fails to validate, it will be dropped from the pool, and we will attempt to borrow another. 
NOTE - for a true value to have any effect, the validationQuery or validatorClassName parameter must be set to a non-null string. 
In order to have a more efficient validation, see validationInterval. 
Default value is false
```

validationQuery:

```
(String) The SQL query that will be used to validate connections from this pool before returning them to the caller. 
If specified, this query does not have to return any data, it just can't throw a SQLException. 
The default value is null. 
Example values are SELECT 1(mysql), select 1 from dual(oracle), SELECT 1(MS Sql Server)
```

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html